# SSIS 2005 - How to figure out what job a sysdtslog90 entry was run under?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Given a entry in a sysdtslog90 table in SQL Server 2005 from an SSIS package, how do you figure out what database agent job the entry was run under?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, after many tests and examination of the data generated, you should be able to piece out this information for your environment(s) from a mix of the computer, operator, and source columns, and maybe the sourceid if that remains consistant between restarts of SQL Agent. Deriving it by correlating between job run times and the starttime and endtime column is also possible, and even more complex options could be worked through setting the value in the datacode column (however that may be done).

I no longer have anything to do with DTS packages, and so do not have (and cannot generate) any such sample data and provide a better answer. (I'd have made this a comment, but no one else has replied yet, so I'm making it a bit more formal.)